# How to pass a string with slashes from view to template?

Tags: python, django

Why does the below code gives me

> SyntaxError: unexpected token: ':'

in the browser's console whenever `test` view is called?

Is it because the JavaScripts sees the text after slashes in the URL as commented lines?

How do I fix that?

The view:

```
 def test(request):
        context = {
            'url': 'https://www.google.com',
        }
        return render(request, 'explorer/test.html', context)
```

The template `test.html`:

```
<script>    
  var url = {{ url }}    
  console.log(url)    
</script>
```

Comment: if url is a string and you're going to write it into JS template, you need to write it as a string.  Templating imperative text ( eg templated javascript ) is imho way, way more trouble than its worth ( you'll also have to escape the quoting characters, special characters, etc).  Write stack JS and load JSON dynamically or call JS with some data from the HTML to protect yourself from having to write 2 languages at once with escapes and templating between.

Comment: @roganjosh Nope, but in Flask it should.

Comment: I've exposed myself as a Flask user :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the safest way to tackle this is to encode it as a JSON blob, and then use the [**`safe`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#safe) template filter to make sure that Django does not escape the string, like:

```
import json

def test(request):
        context = {
            'url': json.dumps('https://www.google.com'),
        }
        return render(request, 'explorer/test.html', context)
```

and then in the template render it like:

```
<script>
  var url = {{ url|safe }}    
  console.log(url)    
</script>
```

If for example the string you aim to transfer would contain a quote, etc., we could end up with the string terminating in advance, with `json.dumps`, this is avoided, for example:

```
>>> json.dumps('"To be or not to be"')
'"\\"To be or not to be\\""'
```

So now we have some guarantees that the output is a valid JavaScript object.

Answer (score 2):

It's a string, you just need to put it in quotes.

```
var url = "{{ url }}";
```

Comment: just make sure `url` doesn't have any quotes in it.  easy in the specific case of urls you generate, but this mechanism of dynamic js gets messy quick.  I'd stick with declarative data formats like json for data whenever possible  so your imperative code can be static.  That also makes it able to be decoupled from the flask end so you can test and develop your frontend independently.